# Where is the actual data stored in blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

I know that the blockchain stores the transnational data and it is immutable but where is the actual data stored?
If there is a use case to replace a centralized data center solution with a blockchain solution, where will the data be stored in blockchain?
Data centers usually have petabytes of raw data, hence I am assuming that a decentralized solution like blockchain won't be able to accommodate large amounts of data.

Note: Many links on google say that blockchain is not an ideal solution for large data, but then any solution will eventually produce an ever increasing amount of data.

Answer (score 3):

In most blockchains, such as bitcoin, every node contains a full set of all data, allowing all nodes to verify previous and new transactions. The data itself is normally stored in a local database, typically leveldb.

As you assumed, for this reason, distributed databases (blockchains) that require a fully copy of the dataset are not ideal for petabytes worth of data. The Bitcoin blockchain is currently roughly 270GB.

Comment: 270 GB per node in blockchain? Ins't that too much duplication with compute and storage wastage?
 Also, If we see the ideal use cases for blockchain like supply chain or healthcare, the data is ever growing. How does blockchain aim to tackle this problem?